# how to open unread tab in firefox extension?

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

is there a way to open a new tab in firefox plugin but without loading it? When I do something like this new tab is opened, but it is immediately loaded with content:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open("http://www.example.com");
```

I'd like to open a set of tabs but keep them unread until user actually activates them.

Makyen suggested using `inBackground: true`, however it still loads a tab with content after opening. I actually need for it to be [`unread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/unread).

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [documentation for `tabs.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#Globals), you need to specify the `inBackground: true` property which does:

> If present and true, the new tab will be opened to the right of the
>   active tab and will not be active. This is an optional property.

Thus, your code would be:

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open({
    url: "http://www.example.com",
    inBackground: true
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as I need. Although the tab is opened and not activated it is still loaded with content. What I need is for it to behave same way as it does when session is restored - tab is created, but unless you actually click it nothing is downloaded from internet. Updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Goto -> Firefox -> Options -> General and under "Tabs" select "Dont't load tab until selected"

This is a non code based solution... I dont now for what you are using it.

Greets
Lukas

Comment: for a plugin I'm writing I need a way to open tabs that are unread at the beginning. I have this setting you've mentioned turned on and a new tab added as described in question is still loaded immediately.